# Search and replace multiple files including subdirectories

Tags: sed

I want to search for all occurrences of:

```
</form>
```

In the current directory and its subdirectories and replace each occurrence with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>
</form>
```

I tried the following on one file. The file was `touch`ed  -- last modified date was changed -- but the replacement was not made:

```
sed -i -re 's/\<\/form\>/\<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="\<cfoutput\>#STOKEN#\<\/cfoutput\>"\>\<\/form\>/gi' ./math.cfm
```

What am I missing? Is there a better command to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\<` and `\>` elements have special meaning in sed regex (as word boundaries).

Don't make things hard by using `/` as sed's separator and trying to get the escaping right - choose an alternate delimiter that doesn't appear in your text, such as `%` or `|`.

The `i` (*insert*) command seems to me to be a more natural choice than the `s` command for this task: you could try

```
'\%</form>% i\<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>'
```

To apply such a command to subdirectories recursively, you can supply the sed command as a `-exec` or `-execdir` argument to `find` e.g.

```
find path/to/dir -type f -name '*.cfm' -execdir sed -i -re '\%</form>% i\<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>' {} +
```

Alternatively, you could use the shell's `globstar` functionality.

Comment: Awesome! That did it; thanks! I can specify the files I want to change in the current folder by replacing `math.cfm` with `*.cfm`. How would I extend this to subfolders?

Comment: @PeterKA please see updated answer