# Replace only certain matches of a string search

Tags: text-processing

Further to my earlier question: [Search and replace multiple files including subdirectories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643612/search-and-replace-multiple-files-including-subdirectories) I wish to make some adjustment so I do not invalidate the CFML. Basically I am trying to avoid nested `<cfoutput></cfoutput>`.

The command:

```
sed -i -re 's/\<\/form\>/\<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="\<cfoutput\>#STOKEN#\<\/cfoutput\>"\>\<\/form\>/gi' ./math.cfm
```

Changes:

```html
</form>
```

To:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>
</form>
```

How would I change the command so that I can achieve the following?

1. If the `</form>` is contained within `<cfoutput>....</cfoutput>`, just insert `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="#STOKEN#"/>`

Thus

```html
<cfoutput>
    ....
    </form>
    ....
</cfoutput>
```

should become:

```html
<cfoutput>
    ....
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="#STOKEN#"/>
    </form>
    ....
</cfoutput>
```

2. However, if the `</form>` is not already enclosed in `<cfoutput>....</cfoutput>` then insert `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>`

Thus

```html
....
</form>
```

should become:

```html
....
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `sed` for that.

Comment: Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformation

Comment: @A.B., thanks for your comment. Can you explain? What would you rather use [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643612/search-and-replace-multiple-files-including-subdirectories)?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: this assumes no `</form>` tags placed on the same line of a `<cfoutput>` or `</cfoutput>` tag, as it seems to be the case from the example; if that's not the case this might misbehave and substitute `</form>` tags preceding a `<cfoutput>` tag following on the same line and `</form>` tags following a `</cfoutput>` tag preceding on the same line with the wrong string. So if your usage case is more complicated than how it actually looks from the example (i.e. you have `</form>` tags in the same line of `<cfoutput>` or `</cfoutput>` tags) you're better off looking into an HTML parser. Otherwise this will work fine.

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/<cfoutput>/,/<\/cfoutput>/ {sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"#STOKEN#\"/>", $0); print; next} {sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>\"/>", $0); print}' infile
```

`awk` script expanded:

```
/<cfoutput>/,/<\/cfoutput>/ {
    sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"#STOKEN#\"/>", $0);
    print;
    next
}
{
    sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>\"/>", $0);
    print
}
```

- `/<cfoutput>/,/<\/cfoutput>/`: executes the following (compound) statement only if the current record is between a record containing a `<cfoutput>` string and a record containing a `</cfoutput>` string;
- `sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"#STOKEN#\"/>", $0);`: replaces every occurence of `</form>` in the current record with `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="#STOKEN#"/>`;
- `print`: prints the current record
- `next`: skips to the next record
- `sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>\"/>", $0);`: replaces every occurence of `</form>` in the current record with `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>`;
- `print`: prints the current record

```
user@debian ~ % cat infile
<html>

<!-- stuff -->

</form>
<cfoutput>
    </form>
</cfoutput>

<!-- stuff -->

</html>
user@debian ~ % awk '/<cfoutput>/,/<\/cfoutput>/ {sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"#STOKEN#\"/>", $0); print; next} {sub(/<\/form>/, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_token\" value=\"<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>\"/>", $0); print}' infile
<html>

<!-- stuff -->

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<cfoutput>#STOKEN#</cfoutput>"/>
<cfoutput>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="#STOKEN#"/>
</cfoutput>

<!-- stuff -->

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have made some modifications and corrections to the sample code.

Comment: @PeterKA The modifications I see in the [revisions history](http://askubuntu.com/posts/649267/revisions) don't rule out the validity of this answer, because the only thing that would would be a `</form>` tag into the same line of an opening / closing `cfoutput` tag, so is that the case? Have you tried the script? Let me know, if that's the case I can try to work out something else

Comment: I'll create a test case and run the code today. I'll let you know how that goes. Thanks.